# Update custom navigationBar trasparent Image autolayout Iphone X?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Tell me how to do it custom navigation bar trasparent  Iphone X?Here is the picture that I want. Here is my code that I did. But when I fix the picture of the changes does not happen. The transparent navigationBar and status bar become ordinary.All my data are shifted which I fixed.
Tell me what else you need to add so that I also had it?

> my code : ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

> AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        // Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        // Sets the translucent background color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
        // Set translucent. (Default value is already true, so this can be removed if desired.)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.88, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent        

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRoxi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SZZ7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add the `UIStatusBarStyle` key to the Info.plist and set the value to `.lightContent`

Comment: method did not work. I have already been installed in Info.plist. tell me more information